# Documentary: Scientist holding guns gets shot from self version in a portal and marble balls animation demonstrating gravity?

Tags: story-identification, movie, science

I saw a documentary or movie about a long time ago (8-10 years ago), where it delved into the to sort of moral or hypothetical situation about space-time or something about that. EDIT: (Most likely of something of high production value, considering it was a long time ago and it looked realistic, at least in the view of my younger self :P)

There is this one scene where the scientist (of Asian descent?) creates a portal of a parallel universe, then holds up a gun. Walks up to the portal and points the gun to a version of himself in that portal. The other version that he sees shoots him and he dies I believe.

There is another scene where there is a whole animated part, where a bunch of marbles is rolled out (on a wooden floor) and then are somehow magically spaced out. I think this was to demonstrated entropy or gravity?

This two scenes might be from two completely different things because I think my dad was watching this from youtube, but hey its worth a shot!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a nice start, but if you check out the [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) you may remember some more details to [edit] into your question.  For example, how many years ago is "a long time?"

Comment: @DavidW Well do, according edits made

Comment: Great, thanks for updating the question!

Comment: This reminds me of something I saw on the H2 channel when I was younger. It might be Into the Universe with Stephen Hawking. In one of those, I remember him explaining how disorder in the early universe created structure in the present universe (he used a bunch of steel marbles on a wooden floor). For the portal part, I remember something similar, but with someone different. Maybe even an entirely different television episode, explaining time travel paradoxes. I'll look into it further later to see if I can write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for Discovery's [Stephen Hawking's Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Universe_with_Stephen_Hawking) (AKA *Into the Universe with Stephen Hawking*) that aired in 3 parts in 2010.

You can see the scene explaining the role of gravity with lots of marbles (metal ball bearings, to be specific) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DECAorZYErk); it's from episode 3 (The Story of Everything). And you can see the main clip you were looking for below; It's actually about *time travel*, and depicts Hawking's version of the grandfather paradox which he coined 'the mad scientist paradox'. This scene stars a young Asian man assembling a gun, then opening up a tiny wormhole to shoot himself *before* he assembled the gun. It's from episode 2 (Time Travel):